# What does it mean to be stubborn?

Tags: meaning

Most definitions of "stubborn" appear to require the person in mind of being wrong on the matter discussed:

- "having or showing dogged determination not to change one's attitude or position on something, especially *in spite of good reasons* to do so."
- "determined not to change your mind, even when people think you are being *unreasonable*"

And examples:

- "They have huge arguments because they're both so stubborn."
- "He was famed for his stubborn resistance and his refusal to *accept defeat*."

What I wonder is whether the stubborn person has to know themselves that they are wrong, or whether it is enough that they are wrong from some third-party or objective perspective?

Can a person be stubborn if they are arguing in good faith, or does it require that they are arguing something "they should know better"?

For example, if two people keep arguing a point for too long, must that be because both of them are stubborn, or can it be that just one of them is - the person who is wrong?

Comment: Being stubborn or flexible is orthogonal to being right or wrong. That's why they are separate word pairs. And being aware or oblivious is, once again, orthogonal to either pair. You can be right, and a dick about it, and you can be wrong, and a dick about it. Or you can be nice. And whether or not you're aware of it doesn't change the fact that you are. And you can even be stubborn about things for which there's no right or wrong in the first place, such as your favorite color, food, car brand, or movie genre.

Comment: @ RegDwigнt♦  ~ Are stubborn people "dicks", then? And is stubbornness not "nice" in your judgment? Just wondering. (Daddy always said I was hard-headed, but I took it as a compliment.)

Comment: How funny: What does it mean to be stubborn? compare: What does being stubborn mean? Try googling: "what does it mean to be" and replace your cursor to the left of your query.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I'm unsure if you're disagreeing with the definitions of the term that I listed?

Comment: @Jason Bassford It's both in the Oxford and Cambridge definitions. Would you not say it's a typical use of the word?

Comment: The word 'stubborn' is polysemous. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stubborn) gives senses: << 1. refusing to comply, agree, or give in; obstinate //...
3.  persistent and dogged >>.  While sense (1) may well be describing a character flaw (emphasised in say [RHK Webster's – their sense 1](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/stubborn)), sense (3) describes a positive trait.

Comment: @Bread I am using a simile to drive home a point. If you think it does the opposite thing, by all means do read around it. It doesn't relate to the question at hand. The question is not about being nice or not nice. It's about being right or wrong. Let's stay on topic.

Comment: RegDwigнt♦ ~ "Or you can be nice." were your own exact words, quoted. How is quoting you off-topic?

Comment: @ThomasAhle I'd say the definitions are fine if you take them for what they are. The supplements after the comma are supplements. "Especially in spite" means "especially in spite". It does not mean "only in spite". Likewise, "even when people disagree" means "even when people disagree", but not "only if people disagree". You can be determined to not change your mind even if you're the last person on Earth.

Comment: @Bread I am not the author of the question. I am the author of the comment. Anything in my comment that does not relate to the question is off-topic. I love turtles. Go ahead, quote that.

Comment: @ RegDwigнt♦  ~ That's funny, you have made me laugh :D You still did not answer my serious question though :/

Comment: @RegDwigнt♦ ~ You seem in your comment to have suggested that stubborn people are "dicks". And that the character trait of stubbornness is not "nice". (By the way: Nice does not = Good).

Comment: @Bread Yes, I seem to have suggested that, which is why later I seem to have suggested that you should be reading around it and not into it. Additionally I clarified in a separate comment that you can be stubborn even when there's not a single person left alive you could possibly be a dick to. My stance on this off-topic issue is clear, but more to the point irrelevant, largely thanks to the fact that the issue is off-topic.

Comment: @Jason Bassford I'm not sure I really understand the other meaning. Is it like Edwin's second definition more like refusing to give in to social/external pressure/failure and persistently keeping fighting? Do you want to add an answer about this meaning?

Answer (score 2):

To start, the question is making an incorrect assumption that **stubbornness** only applies in a negative light—that it's only people who are *wrong* who can be stubborn.

It's perfectly possible for people who are stubborn to be right. Or even nice.

> Mary Poppins stubbornly refused to allow her wards to misbehave, and continually came up with innovative ways to educate them.
>   Ghandi was stubborn when it came to his peaceful demonstrations against authority.
>   Good men will stubbornly stand up to tyrants.

It's also not the case that some people who are being stubborn, and who *do* happen to be wrong, are unaware of their error.

Some people will start off convinced of something and stubbornly stick to it. But even when they comes to realize that they've been arguing for the wrong thing, will continue to try to win the argument anyway. This can occur if they want to "save face," or if they don't want to appear to be a person who makes mistakes.

There is also the possibility that, in an argument, *both* sides are right. (Both could also be wrong . . .) It could be an issue of context or of each person being fixated on, and debating, a specific point rather than figuratively stepping back to look at the larger issue.

Stubbornness is something that can be recognized by everyone, be recognized only by the people observing a person to whom the characteristic is ascribed—while the person themself doesn't see it, or be recognized only by the stubborn person and not seen by anybody else.

---

Somebody submits a manuscript for a book to many different publishers, despite continued rejections and negative comments. The author knows that they are being stubborn, but none of the individual publishers do. The author isn't necessarily wrong or being a nuisance. They could be a perfectly nice person who's written a nice story, but who is patiently (and stubbornly) trying to find the right market for it.

---

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/stubborn) lists several synonyms and related words that *can* put **stubborn** into a negative light:

> Hardheaded, inflexible, ossified, perverse, wayward, wrongheaded, cantankerous, disobedient, deaf to reason.

However, it also lists other words with neutral and even positive meanings:

> Self-willed, unrelenting, determined, persistent, steadfast, stouthearted, defiant, invincible, exacting.

The word **stubborn** has multiple senses and uses. It all depends on context.

Comment: I am delighted to see confirmation of the fact that stubborn can apply to nice people. :)

Comment: Might one say that Mary Poppins is called stubborn because she keeps fighting even after the third party would have considered it reasonable to give up? In the same way, the English may have considered Gandhi stubborn because they thought the pressure applied on him ought to be enough to make him stop protesting? In all cases, the person described is somehow being "unreasonable", at least from a limited perspective.

Comment: @ThomasAhle One *might* say any number of things. :)

Answer (score 1):

> What I wonder is whether the stubborn person has to know themselves that they are wrong, or whether it is enough that they are wrong from some third-party or objective perspective?

In the examples you have given, and with all that we can find online(in this particular context), the word *stubborn* can been seen being used from *some third-party or objective perspective*.

You can have a stubborn murderer, rapist, psychopath; despite of whether he thinks what he is doing is right or wrong.

> if two people keep arguing a point for too long, must that be because both of them are stubborn, or can it be that just one of them is - the person who is wrong?

Let's say, out of two of these one of them is a chain smoker, the other person is his/her spouse.
Both of them are *stubborn*, since both of them are determined in not changing their attitude.  Though from our (society's perspective) the spouse appears to be right. But it isn't about being right and wrong. The chain smoker, deep down might know what he is doing can have bad consequences on his health, family but still could be stubborn because of his habit.

So just keep to the basics, we are using this adjective(stubborn) to give attribute/information to the noun.

Comment: Of course, I could have used these examples. But that's the way I comprehended op's questions.